# Stuck with print popup in Angular 2

Tags: angular

```
`print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    console.log(printContents);
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style/style.css">
        </head>

        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">
        <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
          ${printContents}
        </body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}`
```

When  I am running this code the print popup window is not loading the CSS stylesheet even after adding the delay. Could anyone tell me where I am mistaken? or what should I do to make it work?

Comment: did you try it in the popdown window?

Comment: Why is your method in a string? If you're trying to "print" a javascript method that is printing HTML with <link> tags in it, it MIGHT not work.. and it's probably not a good way to do what you're trying to do. Have you tried actually opening a window containing the actual HTML in it?

Also.. this might not be an Angular 2 question.